# filter object list based on child element of object in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

This is my object structure in MongoDB, [View JSON structure here](https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=b1c42e356bda4ac4afa2358bb94e2b9c)

`{
  "id": 1234,
  "hotel_id": 1, 
  "data":[
    { 
      "date":"2019-06-21",
      "price": "150",
      "updated_at":"2019-05-20"
    },
    {
      "date":"2019-06-22",
      "price": "155",
      "updated_at":"2019-05-20"
    },
    {
      "date":"2019-06-23",
      "price": "157",
      "updated_at":"2019-05-20"
    },
    {
      "date":"2019-06-24",
      "price": "159",
      "updated_at":"2019-05-21"
    },
    {
      "date":"2019-06-25",
      "price": "159",
      "updated_at":"2019-05-22"
    },
    {
      "date":"2019-06-26",
      "price": "159",
      "updated_at":"2019-05-23"
    }
  ]
}`

I want to filter records that have updated_at > `2019-05-21` (x date) .

Does it possible to get data between two specific dates like I want data which dates between `2019-06-21` and `2019-06-23`, don't want to get other records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this current design you'll have to use an aggregate, i don't really know what your product is but this just feels a little off to me, i think (if possible) you should consider re-structuring the data.

With that said i would do it like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate(
    [
        { 
            "$addFields" : {
                "temp" : {
                    "$objectToArray" : "$data"
                }
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$match" : {
                "temp.v.updated_at" : {
                    "$gt" : "2019-05-21"
                }
            }
        }
    ], 
);
```

Edit:
to count the records just add a $group stage with $sum:

```
{
  $group: {
     _id: null,
     count: {$sum: 1}
  }
}
```

Comment: what structured you would suggest? I have to update data continuously too using date.

Comment: again i'm not sure exactly what you do, it really depends on that. its just that a structure like this which uses specific dates as key's feels off

Comment: I second @tomslabbaert on this. The "data" needs better structuring

Comment: @tomslabbaert, I change my format, now how does it work and I want the number of records too, like if there are 2 records which have update_at > date then it should return number only

Comment: i edited the answer, quite simple - just add a final group stage to count the number of records.